# How can be pasted remotely a locally copied file in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, clipboard, remote-desktop

A file (from File Explorer) has been copied using < Ctrl > < C >. The content of the file must be pasted into a RichTextBox, if the file is a picture (e.g. in JPG format) - similarly to Microsoft Word.
It's already implemented and works without any problem - but only locally. If the copied file was on a Remote Desktop Computer, it doesn't work. The question is: why?

Copy/paste works remotely without any problem, e.g. a simple text (not a file!) or a picture (opened in Paint) can be copied/pasted (has been checked by Free Clipboard Viewer 4.0).

Some additional information:

1. Locally copied file

Clipboard contains data "DataFormats.FileDrop". Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats() gives the following string array:

```
[0] "Shell IDList Array"
[1] "DataObjectAttributes"
[2] "DataObjectAttributesRequiringElevation"
[3] "Shell Object Offsets"
[4] "Preferred DropEffect"
[5] "AsyncFlag"
[6] "FileDrop"
[7] "FileNameW"
[8] "FileName"
[9] "FileContents"
[10]    "FileGroupDescriptorW"
```

The whole path can be gained using Clipboard.GetFileDropList()[0] (or with FileNameW), and the picture can be imported into my application.

2. Remotely copied file

The format of the data is unknown (cannot be found in DataFormats class). Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats() gives the following string array:

```
[0] "FileGroupDescriptorW"
[1] "FileContents"
[2] "Preferred DropEffect"
[3] "CanIncludeInClipboardHistory"
[4] "CanUploadToCloudClipboard"
```

Using "FileGroupDescriptorW" the name of the file (without the path) can be gained out. Only the filename, without any path information (most probably the locally valid path information wouldn't be sense remotely).

Clipboard.GetData("FileContents") throws an exception:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Data on clipboard is invalid (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401D3 (CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA))'

However the remotely copied file:

1. can be pasted into the local file system, or
2. can be pasted e.g. into Microsoft Word
   without any problem. It means, that the content of the copied file can be found on the Clipboard - but not accessible. Most probably the "FileContents" should be suitable to get it.

Do you have any idea?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using:

```
string lTempPath = "Insert some path here";
Stream lStream = null;
        MemoryStream lMemoryStream = null;
        try
        {
            lStream = (Stream)Clipboard.GetData("FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW"); //FileGroupDescriptorW
            if (lStream == null)
                lStream = (Stream)Clipboard.GetData("FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORA"); //FileGroupDescriptorA

            if (lStream != null)
            {
                string[] lFileNames = ReadFilenamesFromStream(lStream);
                if (lFileNames != null)
                {
                    lMemoryStream = (MemoryStream)Clipboard.GetData("FileContents");
                    if (lMemoryStream == null)
                        lMemoryStream = (MemoryStream)Clipboard.GetData("CFSTR_FILECONTENTS");

                    if (lMemoryStream != null)
                    {
                        var lFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(lFileNames[0]);
                        var lFileName = lFileNames[0];
                        lFileNames = null;
                        if (lMemoryStream != null)
                        {
                             lMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                                //save at temp path
                                
                                using (FileStream lFileStream = new FileStream(lTempPath, FileMode.Create))
                                {
                                    lMemoryStream.WriteTo(lFileStream);
                                }
                                return new string[1] { lTempPath };
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

the ReadFilenamesFromStream(lStream) method does the following:

```
try
        {
            using (BinaryReader lReader = new BinaryReader(aStream))
            {
                var count = lReader.ReadUInt32();
                var lFileNames = new string[count];
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    //Flags
                    var Flags = lReader.ReadUInt32();
                    //ClassID
                    var ClassId = new Guid(lReader.ReadBytes(16));
                    //Size
                    var Size = new Size(lReader.ReadInt32(), lReader.ReadInt32());
                    //Point
                    var Point = new Point(lReader.ReadInt32(), lReader.ReadInt32());
                    //FileAttributes
                    var FileAttributes = (FileAttributes)lReader.ReadUInt32();
                    //CreationTime
                    var CreationTime = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1).AddTicks(lReader.ReadInt64());
                    //LastAccessTime
                    var LastAccessTime = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1).AddTicks(lReader.ReadInt64());
                    //LastWriteTime
                    var LastWriteTime = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1).AddTicks(lReader.ReadInt64());
                    //FileSize
                    var FileSize = lReader.ReadInt64();
                    //FileName
                    byte[] nameBytes = lReader.ReadBytes(520);
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < nameBytes.Length)
                    {
                        if (nameBytes[i] == 0 && nameBytes[i + 1] == 0)
                            break;
                        i++; //yes, increase two times
                        i++;
                    }
                    string FileName = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(nameBytes, 0, i);
                    lFileNames[lFileNames.Length - count] = FileName;
                    count--;
                }
                return lFileNames;
            }
        }
```